# Multiple pipelines for one commit?

Tags: git, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

When I commit changes to the gitlab repo, I expect that the one pipeline is triggered which ideally should run all my specified jobs but that's not the case. 4 pipelines are created everytime. I have only one runner, that is docker and has 3 tags: build, deploy, test.

I simplified the file below but still can not figure out where the problem is.

.gitlab-ci.yml

```
image: alpine:3.8

some_job:
 tags:
  - test
 script:
  - echo "Test passed"
```

4 pipelines! for just 1 commit. Why not just 1 pipeline because all pipelines are doing the exact same work.
[image]

Comment: stages:
  - test
  - acceptation
  - deploy

Comment: does this happen on gitlab.com? and this happens for each commit?

Comment: @Danny Yes, for every commit.

Comment: GitLab.com? Or private instance? Version, cause this is absolutely not correct and not reproducible

Comment: It's on gitlab and reproducible, still no solution for me :(

Answer (score 2):

define 1 stage in stages
and define your job with that stage as below

```
stages:
  - test

testdeploy:
  stage: test
```

Comment: I have tried this too, tried it again but problem still persists.

Comment: could you share the whole yml? I will take a look

Comment: Pastebin expired. But yes, you mixed tags and stages. Tags are to identify a runner, stage is to place in a stage of your pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing the same issue on my on premise GitLab server (12.7.5). My issue was that I had an invalid (outdated) runner tag on one of my stages.

Double check that you've got a runner that will work with that project and that "test" tag.